# How to refer to a set of lines where each line is either parallel to $x$-axis or $y$-axis

Tags: geometry, terminology

Suppose that there are $k$ lines on the plane that are parallel to $x$-axis along with $m$ lines parallel to $y$-axis, not necessarily spaced equally.

Is there a technical term for these kind of line sets? My intention is to refer to them as *parallel-orthogonal straight lines* but it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about "axes-parallel"?

--- rk

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal for parallel to $x-axis$ and vertical for parallel to $y-axis.$

Comment: That is a nice suggestion, but these two terms describe two different set of lines. I am looking for a term to define union of them.

Comment: Straight lattice??